# safe way to delete billions of data from big query table when it was inserted new data every 5 mins

Tags: google-bigquery

we have a BQ table contains nearly 30 billion rows of data, we decided to keep data that only inserted from 2022. However, we have a ML model that still inserts new data into our table every 5 minutes. Do you have any suggestion how we can safely delete the data we don't want anymore and still insert the new data without any problem? We cannot let it crash. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with standard DML, is there a field that would be specific only to the 2022 data?

```
DELETE FROM `datasetid.tableid` WHERE year = 2022
```

Comment: Hi Yes! I think so. Maybe I was not clear enought in my question. We actually want to keep data started from 2022.